# Accessing AWS parameter store values with custom KMS key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to read AWS parameters from the parameter store using java, i have created the parameters using a custom encryption key. I dont see a sample code in the internet where its using a custom KMS key , the below is the code i currently have which is working (here we are usingthe default KMS key).

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement client= AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    GetParametersRequest request= new GetParametersRequest();
    request.withNames("test.username","test.password")
           .setWithDecryption(true);
```

This will give the results with default KMS key
Does anyone know how to handle this if we have a custom KMS key

Comment: Can you please add the full sample for reading/modifying aws parameter store not getting any working sample on this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `GetParameters` API, there's no difference between use default KMS key or custom KMS key. It always works like your code. Just make sure the permission for the credential includes the custom key.

The difference only at `PutParameter` API, when using a default KMS key, you don't need to specify it, when using a custom KMS key, you set its KeyId to the custom key. The KeyId can be one of following examples:

- Key ARN Example arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789012:key/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
- Alias ARN Example - arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789012:alias/MyAliasName
- Globally Unique Key ID Example - 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
- Alias Name Example - alias/MyAliasName

Comment: You are right , no difference in using default key or custom key.

Comment: interesting bc the cli doesn't allow putting an arn currently

Answer (score 15):

just in case, if somebody looking for this (with Default encryption Key)

```
protected Parameter getParameterFromSSMByName(String parameterKey)
  {
    AWSCredentialsProvider credentials = InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance();
    AWSSimpleSystemsManagement simpleSystemsManagementClient = (AWSSimpleSystemsManagement)((AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder)((AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder)AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentials)).withRegion("us-east-1")).build();
    GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = new GetParameterRequest();
    parameterRequest.withName(parameterKey).setWithDecryption(Boolean.valueOf(true));
    GetParameterResult parameterResult = simpleSystemsManagementClient.getParameter(parameterRequest);
    return parameterResult.getParameter();
  }
```

Comment: Well, your answer ended my 2 days search to access AWS Parameter store values using access keys.

Comment: @NaveenKumar AWSCredentialsProvider is an interface. I used this to make sure it support for all sorts for credentials (for other users). 
you could have [check this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/auth/EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.html)

Answer (score 8):

Here is @Extreme's answer as a class with imports and a bit of cleanup:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;                                                                   
import com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagement;
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder;

import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.GetParameterRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.GetParameterResult;

public class AWSSsmHelper
{
    private AWSCredentialsProvider credentials = InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getInstance();
    private AWSSimpleSystemsManagement simpleSystemsManagementClient =
        AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credentials)).withRegion("us-east-1")).build();                    

    public String getParameterFromSSMByName(String parameterKey) {
        GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = new GetParameterRequest();
        parameterRequest.withName(parameterKey).setWithDecryption(Boolean.valueOf(true));
        GetParameterResult parameterResult = simpleSystemsManagementClient.getParameter(parameterRequest);
        return parameterResult.getParameter().getValue();
    }
}
```